# PHP replace special characers

Tags: php, character-encoding, special-characters

I am trying to get IP details from this page `http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=` in PHP.

But sometimes it returns some characters like this `&scaron;`. Is there any way to replace it with the respective character (`&scaron;` - š)?

Comment: [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try function [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net//manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: Ok thanks. This is working, but when I save it in database it converts again to `&scaron;`. Is there a way I can replace all these characters with alphabetic characters (so only A-Z, a-z, 0-9).

Comment: @Enve The database does not encode text to HTML entities, unless *you* do it. You just need to handle encoding/decoding correctly. Converting the characters is not a solution for a mishandled text encoding workflow. Maybe see a few of the articles here to get you started: http://kunststube.net